# How can I write a .sh file that modifies the Ubuntu kernel boot parameters?

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, bash, scripts

I know that GRUB kernel boot parameters, for example `panic=-1` can be added by `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and then `sudo update-grub`.

My application comes with a `setup.sh` shell script that sets everything up for the user, as I want it to be able to be used by the non-technically minded user. Anyway, a driver called `intel_pstate` makes my app not work, so on devices where `intel_pstate` is detected, I want the `setup.sh` file to add `intel_pstate=disable` to the kernel boot parameters/boot line.

I really don't want to have to tell users to edit the boot parameters themselves, and am looking for a way to, in shell script code, add `intel_pstate=disable` to the boot parameters while maintaining the existing boot parameters.

**What I've already tried**

- Use this code (in a sudo bash shell):

```bash
cat /etc/default/grub > grub_bkp
echo "intel_pstate=disable" >> grub_bkp
echo gurb_bkp > /etc/default/grub
```

- This doesn't work, take the following /etc/default/grub file for example:

```
GRUB_OTHER_STUFF=1
...
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='panic=-1 init=/my/cool/file.sh'
```

- After my script is done with it, it will look like the following, not successfully applying the kernel boot parameter:

```
GRUB_OTHER_STUFF=1
...
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='panic=-1 init=/my/cool/file.sh'
intel_pstate=disable
```

Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: A hint: If you replace this string: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='` with this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='intel_pstate=disable ` it should work as intended. Look into `sed`.

Comment: @ArturMeinild, thank you so much for your help! It worked. I didn't know `sed` was a thing before. Do you want to write this up as an answer so you can get reputation from upvote and accept?

Comment: If your software is intended for the public, a word of warning: I'd consider modifying system parameters like this and increasing the power consumption of my system pretty rude. If I found a piece of software that does that on a system I admin, that software would be gone pretty quickly. Also consider that it may possible to make your software work with pstate enabled, so this is potentially the wrong solution altogether.

Comment: @marcelm, thank you for your reply! I'm modified my applications install file, so it says 'Intel Pstate detected. Do you consent to removing it as it causes issues? [Y/N]. Also, my app IS a power saving app, and it can't change clock speeds with pstate enabled. I've done tests and my app greatly outweighs the savings of pstate. I'll try to get it to work with pstate tonight. Have a great day!

Comment: @Android776 Fair enough; I agree it's a good idea to inform the user and/or ask permission. Do you have an uninstall procedure? If so, that should probable revert this change. Also, consider including a comment in `/etc/default/grub` that explains the purpose of disabling pstate so anyone editing that file understands why that parameter is there and what the consequences of removing it are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sed` to inject a string after the search pattern `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='`:

```
sed -i "s/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='/&intel_pstate=disable /" /etc/default/grub
```

After that, also make sure the script updates the GRUB configuration:

```
update-grub
```

The entire script should run as root, since root is required for the above commands.

Comment: Also, don't forget `update-grub` on the following line.